# Pydio Amazon S3 custom server

Tags: amazon-s3, pydio

I trying to integrate S3fs into Pydio to use my own storage servers (so not amazon).
Accessing an s3fs mount as local filesystem from Pydio is malfunctioning, there are bunch of commands like ls which doesnt work on it therefore I must use the aws-sdk to interface with it from pydio.

The problem is that from the Amazon SDK it's only possible to select Amazons own servers through a region drop down list. To complicate things I also need to use proxy to access my own s3 storage.

Did anyone manage to implement this?

Using just the amazon Sdk how would this look like from php?

What I tried:

```
<?php

        require_once("/usr/share/pydio/plugins/access.s3/aS3StreamWrapper/lib/wrapper/aS3StreamWrapper.class.php");

    use Aws\S3\S3Client;

        if (!in_array("s3", stream_get_wrappers())) {
            $wrapper = new aS3StreamWrapper();
            $wrapper->register(array('protocol' => 's3',
                  'http' => array(
                      'proxy' => 'proxy://10.0.0.1:80',
                      'request_fulluri' => true,
                  ),
                  'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_OWNER_FULL_CONTROL,
                  'key' => "<key>",
                  'secretKey' => "<secret>",
                  'region' => "s3.myprivatecloud.lan"));
        }
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if this is still a pending question, FYI in the latest versions (v6 beta 2) we've changed the `access.s3` plugin to use the last version of `aws-sdk`, and also we added some parameters to easily use this plugin pointing to alternative s3-compatible storages.
-c